# Hitting Linkedin API using Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am stuck at some point. I want to hit the linkedin API (WITHOUT using any package) and get the profile information of the user.

So for this, I am following these steps:
1. Hit the linkedin API to get authorization code
2. Use this auth code to get the access token.
3. Using access token to get the profile info.

So far, I am being able to get the authorization code, but not being able to proceed further. Here are my codes:

These are just for testing purpose so doing everything on the client.

My template

```
<template name="home">
    <a href="#" class="callLinkedIn">get profile from linkedin</a> 
</template>
```

My helpers

```
var clientId='XXXXX';
var secret = 'XXXXX';
var redirectUri = 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2F_oauth%2Flinkedin%3Fclose';
var credentialToken = "RANDOMSTRING";


Template.home.events({
    'click .callLinkedIn':function(event,template){
        var scope = [];
        var loginUrl =
            'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization' +
            '?response_type=code' + '&client_id=' + clientId +
            '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri +
            '&scope=' + scope + '&state=' + credentialToken;

        showPopup(loginUrl,function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log('success');
                var params = {
                    'grant_type':'authorization_code',
                    'code':Session.get('code'),
                    'redirect_uri':redirectUri,
                    'client_id':clientId,
                    'client_secret':secret
                };

                HTTP.call('POST',"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken", {
                        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        params:params
                    },
                    function(err,res){
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log(res);
                        }
                    });
            }
        })

    }
})

function showPopup(url, callback, dimensions) {                                                      
    var popup = openCenteredPopup(                                                       
        url,                                                                             
        (dimensions && dimensions.width) || 650,                                         
        (dimensions && dimensions.height) || 331                                         
    );                                                                                   

    var checkPopupOpen = setInterval(function() {                                        
        try {                                                                            
            var popupClosed = popup.closed || popup.closed === undefined;                
        } catch (e) {                                                                    
            return;                                                                      
        }                                                                                

        if (popupClosed) {
            console.log(popup.document.URL);
            var url = popup.document.URL;
            var a1 = url.split('code=');
            var a2 =a1[1].split('&');
            Session.set('code',a2[0]);
            clearInterval(checkPopupOpen);                                              
            callback();                                                                 
        }                                                                               
    }, 50);                                                                             
}

function openCenteredPopup(url, width, height) {                                 
    var screenX = typeof window.screenX !== 'undefined'                          
        ? window.screenX : window.screenLeft;                                    
    var screenY = typeof window.screenY !== 'undefined'                          
        ? window.screenY : window.screenTop;                                     
    var outerWidth = typeof window.outerWidth !== 'undefined'                    
        ? window.outerWidth : document.body.clientWidth;                         
    var outerHeight = typeof window.outerHeight !== 'undefined'                  
        ? window.outerHeight : (document.body.clientHeight - 22);                             
    var left = screenX + (outerWidth - width) / 2;                               
    var top = screenY + (outerHeight - height) / 2;                              
    var features = ('width=' + width + ',height=' + height +                     
    ',left=' + left + ',top=' + top + ',scrollbars=yes');                 

    var newwindow = window.open(url, 'Login', features);                 
    if (newwindow.focus)                                                 
        newwindow.focus();                                               
    return newwindow;                                                    
}
```

I get the pop up with linkedin username and password. But when I give the credentials and press "allow access", I am getting this error in browser console.

POST https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:// localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

And also in the server, I got this
Unable to parse state from OAuth query: DC8ÄDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

This was very puzzling. Cos there was no error in my code. But finally I found out that the problem was with the linkedin app. I was using the above code for the app that was created about 6 months ago. But when I tried with the newly created app it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Since the error says that there is no header called `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`, try adding the header like so:

```
HTTP.call('POST',
  "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken", {
    headers : {
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'  
    },
    params : params
  },
  function(err,res){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
```

Try and let us know if it works

Comment: Hi, I tried .. still it is giving the same solution. I am really wondering what is the problem. Any idea, for how long does the authorization code last? Somewhere I read for 20s, but I did not see it in the linkedin doc. Is it because my auth code is getting expired? But I am calling it the moment it is created

Comment: You're getting the exact same error message after fixing the headers? I don't think the auth code is the problem.

Comment: Yes I am getting the same error in the console. You can try the above code in ur system and see it in console.

Comment: Maybe is not the solution... but you can try reducing the scope parameter. Linkedin changed their perrmision policy. Nowadays you can't do many things with the new policy....

Comment: What do u mean by changing scope parameters